# How to write a function that will return a dictionary containing data loaded from a text file

Tags: python

This is what I have so far, right now I get sankey is not defined.

```
    def makeSankey (inf):

     sankey = {}
     with open("file.txt") as f:
         for line in f:
            (key, val) = line.split()
            sankey[str(key)] = val



     return makeSankey()

    for i in sankey():
     print(i),sankey[i]`
```

The text file looks like this:

```
    Single,2106
    Double,603
    Triple,44
    Home Run,431
    Walk / HBP,1402
    Sacrifice Out,137
    Other Out,8160
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of how `file.text` looks like?

Comment: `sankey` is a local variable within the `makeSankey()` function, but you're trying to access it outside the function, where it is not known.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Comment: Also, at the end of the function, I think you want `return sankey`, not `return makeSankey()`.

Comment: Can you provide a better example of the file contents?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't access `sankey` outside the function.
You can't call `sankey` as it's not your function's name which is `makeSankey`.
What you meant to do with `return makeSankey` was probably return the value, which is stored in `sankey` so you `return sankey`.

Your code in fixed condition should be something like this, I still am not sure about the input if it's the same as you provided but you can try it:

```py
def makeSankey(fileName):
    sankey = {}
    with open(fileName) as f:
        for line in f:
            (key, val) = line.split()
            sankey[key] = val
    return sankey

data = makeSankey("file.txt")

for i in data:
    print(i, data[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

This works if `file.txt` contains lines like `key,val`. use `python script.py file.txt`

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import sys

def makeSankey(file_name):
    sankey = {}
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            (key,val) = line.split(",")
            # strip to remove \n
            sankey[key] = val.strip()

    # return the dic to the caller
    return sankey

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # received file name as an argument, if not then just pass it to makeSankey fun
    sanKeyDic = makeSankey(sys.argv[1])
    print(sanKeyDic)
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works and OP's does not? I.e. explain why return sankey is required rather than returning the function call

Comment: I fixed up my code but I am receiving this error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.txt'. I will add in all my other code to show you. I want the name of the file to be provided as a command line argument. I am using IDLE 3 btw.

Comment: Use `sys.argv` to read the arguments `argv[0]` is the name of the program itself, `argv[1]` is the name of the first argument, file.txt in this case. check the code up.